# No sample utterances in the documentation for google smart home action

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there any list of sample utterances to the google smart home device types/traits? Since, google smarthome action device types/traits are pre-built, It's terrible not stating some sample utterances under each device type/trait in the google action developer documentation. Otherwise, developer has no clue what are supported utterances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a specific issue you're seeing, as there are sample utterances in the trait documentation, [Brightness](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/brightness) for example has sample utterances under the **Examples** heading.

[image]

Comment: Got it!, i might have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

As already update by Nick there are plenty of utterances available, but since it is smarthome as AI you can try and figure out the multiple utterances which are not available in the DOCS.

Cheers.